# What defined the Alien- & UFO sterotypes?

Tags: origin

What movie/series or who has defined sterotypes like:

- Aliens are gray
- UFOs are some kind of disk
- UFOs pick up cows with a beam

and the list goes on but you probably know what I mean.

Comment: Abducted people often describe grey aliens se wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_alien

Comment: Hi ... I've closed this as too broad or being too subjective ... there could be a whole list of Alien movies from the 1950's onwards that may contribute to today's stereotype.  Is there a way you can phrase this to be a little more specific or less subjective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close Encounter of the 3rd Kind is a well-known one for "Greys".